# Laravel 5.5 - Class Custom BaseController not found but exists

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, namespaces, laravel-5.5

Laravel 5.5 Custom `BaseController` not found even though it exists. Have checked the other questions on `StackOverflow` regarding the `BaseController` not found but they are referring to the default `BaseController` which isn't the same in mine case.

Here is my implementation

## Controller.php

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as CheckController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

class Controller extends CheckController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;


}
```

## Custom BaseController (BaseController.php)

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class BaseController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Setup the layout used by the controller.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $data = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        if (Sentinel::check()) {
            // User is not logged in, or is not activated
            $this->data['admin'] = Sentinel::getUser();
        }
    }

    protected function setupLayout()
    {
        if (!is_null($this->layout)) {
            $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
        }
    }

}
```

Extending a class named `HomeCtontroller` to Custom `BaseController`

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {

    protected $layout = 'master';

    public function main()
    {
         ...
    }

}
```

And then it gives the following error

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
Class 'BaseController' not found
```

Would appreciate any sort of pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you haven't included full namespaces.

Make sure in BaseController you have:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

and in `HomeController` make sure you are using:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\BaseController;
```

all those controllers should be located in `app/Http/Controllers` directory.

If you are sure you have valid directories and namespaces run `composer dump-autoload` in console

Comment: I think all he needs to do is put in the namespace. You don't need to import from the same namespace.