# Laravel 5.5 controller not found

Tags: laravel

Basically I have the same error as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47380843/laravel-5-5-class-custom-basecontroller-not-found-but-exists). I tried that solution but still I got the same error. Any suggestions also it seems that is something related with the namespaces but if I change the App folder to app I got different error

[image: Example1]

[image: Example2]

[image: Example3]

Comment: You should post your relevant code and artisan command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
```

Import the main controller

Also remove the comment from the base controller and remove any white space

Comment: thank you for your comment "DumbAnswersForDumbQuestions" Sorry for not being professional and high skill level programmer. No one is a master when we start to learn something new.